# How to reuse methods for jQuery DOM variables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, prototype

I'm accessing DOM elements with jQuery, and I want to add methods to the variables, like this:

```
var nav = $("nav"),
    footer = $("footer");

nav.visibility = function() {
    return nav.css("display") !== "none";
}
```

However, I'm going to be checking things like `if (nav.visibility() == true) {...}` and `if (footer.visibility() == true) {...}` for both variables. How can I have a method that can be used by both `nav` and `footer`?

At the moment I'm thinking, is there some way I can make them instances of a prototype with a `visibility` method?

Or should I settle for this:

```
function visibility(element) {
    return element.css("display") !== "none";
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that when you can just do `nav.is(':visible')` etc

Comment: @adeneo Thanks, that's helpful for what I'm working on. Nevertheless, the question still stands

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to check something like

```
var nav = $("nav");

if ( nav.visibility() == true ) {...
```

You'll need to write it as a plugin

```
$.fn.visibility = function() {
    return this.css("display") !== "none";
}
```

Comment: Ya that's correct BUT it would work only on first matched element in set. That's OP's example which is quite unrelevant, indeed

Comment: @A.Wolff - indeed, and that's what most similar jQuery methods do, they return the result for the first element in the collection. It's not really clear if the OP wants more, for instance check against all elements, some elements etc ?

Comment: @A.Wolff to be clear, there's only one nav and one footer in my webpage

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you want

```
nav.add(footer).visibility()
// if you have own "jQuery.fn.visible" function
```

extended version (should probably work better)

```
!nav.add(footer).is(':not(:visible)')
// tests, is there an invisible element
```